# Docker Compose NGINX Proxy and Static Files

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, docker-compose

For some reason, my docker-compose/node/nginx stack is having trouble serving static files. The reverse proxy side works but serving my css and javascript fails. For every static file requested, I get an error like this:

```
customnginx_1 | 2016/03/29 22:42:13 [error] 6#6: *1 open()     
"/var/www/static/styles/normalize.css" failed (2: No such file or     
directory), client: 192.168.99.1, server: , request: "GET     
/styles/normalize.css HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.99.100", referrer:     
"http://192.168.99.100/"
```

How do I properly link my "static" directory to my nginx container so these files are served correctly?
Relevant code:

docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
  image: postgres:latest
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: sizzeDog
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: awfulPassword
    POSTGRES_DB: ceres

ceres:
  build: .
  links:
    - db
  environment:
    POSTGRES_HOST: db
    POSTGRES_USER: sizzeDog
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: awfulPassword
    NODE_ENV: production
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/

customnginx:
  build: nginx/.
  links:
    - ceres
  volumes:
    - static:/var/www/static
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN npm install pm2 -g

VOLUME ["/var/www"]
ADD start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod 755 /start.sh

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

nginx/nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_min_length   500;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                      text/comma-separated-values
                      text/javascript
                      application/x-javascript
                      application/atom+xml;

    # List of application servers
    upstream app_server {

        server ceres:5000;
    }

  server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/static;

    location /styles/ {}
    location /dist/ {}

    location / {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass         http://app_server;
    }
  }
}
```

nginx/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

VOLUME ["/var/www/static"]

RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

UPDATE: Adding `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;` to the http block of the `nginx.conf` fixed the empty css issue :).

Comment: I don't see any errors here.  Or a question.

Comment: Where are you adding the files to `/var/www/static`? I see you mark that directory as a volume both inside the Dockerfile, and use a "named" volume in your docker-compose file; `static:/var/www/static`, but I don't see where you're adding the actual files to that directory

Comment: @thaJeztah Is there a way for me to bind the directory "static" (which is in the directory where the first Dockerfile and the docker-compose.yml file resides) to the nginx container without having to bake it into the image? Because, ideally, I'd like the contents of "static" to be updated (through a git deploy) without requiring the image to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

In nginx file, try it:

```
location /static/{
        alias  /var/www/static/;
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

css & js & img ,....should be in the same folder as below:

```
/var
-/www
 -/static
  -/css
  -/js
  -/img
```

Comment: For some reason, only the javascript is actually served. The css files are listed in the Chrome dev tools sources but are empty.

Comment: please make sure, css and js folder are in the same folder

Comment: They are in directories within the "static" directory ("dist" and "styles").

Comment: make sure the path to css files and js files are right

Comment: I believe that the problem lies more in the Docker/docker-compose side than the nginx side. From my very limited knowledge, it appears as though the file requests are being handled properly by nginx, it's just that the files are not in the container.

Comment: UPDATE: Upon running `docker exec d778 cat /var/www/static/styles/skeleton.css` on the nginx container, it appears as though the files are being correctly mounted. However, there are no logs of requests to the static files. In what context is the code listed above meant to be in? I'm unclear on the "/home/source/static/" directory and if it should be replaced with "/var/www/static".

Comment: alias  /home/source/static/; is just for example, in your case alias /var/www/static/;

Comment: Hmmm, still getting the same weird issue where the css files are completely empty but the javascript file is fine. For context, I did change the `expires 1y;` line to "1h" and `access_log off;` to on for my own usage requirements (the javascript file will be updated somewhat frequently).

Comment: My script tag is `<script src="/static/dist/bundle.js"></script>` and changing the css tags from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles/normalize.css">` to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.99.100/static/styles/normalize.css">` (where the IP address is that of my `docker-machine ip`) made no difference.

Comment: try: <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script> & <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/normalize.css">

Comment: Produces a 404 error in the chrome dev tools console that did not occur before